# How do I change permissions for only the folder and no subfolders or files contained therein?

Tags: chmod

I need to change permissions for a root folder, then change them straight back. All permissions for everything else should stay the same.

So, I need to

1. find out current permissions
2. change them to what I need for base directory *only*
3. change them back.

How do I do that?

Comment: Sounds pretty simple.  What have you learned from your research?  How much of this can you do?  I hope you know how to do the second step.  If somebody told you how to do the first step, would you then be able to do the third?  What have you tried? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Commands you might want to consider are `stat` and `ls`, and to find out how to use them `man stat` or `man ls`. You are clearly already aware of `chmod`, but see `man chmod` for its detail.